# Docker ENV vars updated in container but not in application

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

I've updated an environment variable in my Dockerfile, restarted with `docker compose up -d`

Adding in a shell file to be run on container start, with the line `echo $MY_VAR`, echoes the appropriate value, however, when I go open the browser console within my application and type `env`, it only prints out my previous env.

I've tried clearing my cache, force rebuilding of the image via the `-d` flag on docker compose up, deleting the old images, literally anything and everything, yet somehow the old env remains.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:17.4.0-alpine3.14

WORKDIR /code

CMD ["bin/run"]

ENV \
  MY_VAR='abcdef' \
  VERSION='development'

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY src src
COPY cogs.js ./
COPY bin bin

RUN bin/build
```

My Docker Compose

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  balancer:
    image: nginx:1.19.7-alpine
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./src/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - www.dev.mydomain.com

  app: &app
    build: 
      context: "../app"
    volumes:
      - ../app/bin:/code/bin
      - ../app/package-lock.json:/code/package-lock.json
      - ../app/package.json:/code/package.json
      - ../app/src:/code/src
      - app-dist:/code/dist
    environment:
      MY_VAR: abcdef
      VERSION: 'development'

  app-watch:
    <<: *app
    command: ["bin/watch"]

volumes:
  app-dist:
```

Where I use it in my app; config.js

```
const { env } = globalThis;

export default {
  myVar: env.MY_VAR,
  version: env.VERSION
};
```

Updated docker vars (STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY === MY_VAR)
[image: Reflective docker vars]

I'm honestly completely confused as to how the variables can be updated when I echo `$MY_VAR` in my `bin/run` script, but logging out the env in browser returns an outdated version of the env.

Comment: The browser won't usually be able to see the server's environment.  (Nothing specific to Docker; if you `export MY_VAR=ghijk; npm run start` you also won't be able to see that environment variable.)  How is the variable being used?

Comment: It's not the server's environment, it's the container holding the environment, meaning it should in theory be available in the globalThis variable AFAIK. I'll add in my `config.js` file to my question where I pull out the envvar for use in my application. The actual variable is my stripe public testing key which I need to initialize the Stripe library. I've been pulling out the VERSION envvar since my initial commit, and it's currently the only thing showing up when I log out env
EDIT: added example (below docker-compose)

Comment: We would be able to provide better answers if you could provide us with a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example): ideally, something we could run locally to reproduce the problem you're describing. If that's not possible, some more details would help: for example, in your `docker-compose.yaml` you're setting the environment variables `VERSION` and `MY_VAR` to the same values they have in the `Dockerfile`, so of course they have the same value.

Comment: The redundant docker compose envvars were simply me trying everything to update my values, I'll try and see if I can boil it down further but I feel like I've been in a similar position before and there was some solution that fixed it, but I've been unable to find the existing solution. I believe it had something to do with deleting and rebuilding existing volumes? But I already removed app-dist from the docker compose and bin/up'd but that didn't solve it. I'll try to get a minimal repro up.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not put the variable in both, `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` (unless you explicitly need it that way to build the app), but either in `docker-compose.yml` or in a `.env` file.

Start by [`docker compose build`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/build/) if the images depend on the env vars during build stage.

Docker detects the changes when running [`docker compose up`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/) but if you want to force recreate, use the `--force-recreate` flag. (`-d` is used to detach the container from the session).

[`docker compose restart`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/restart/) is not suitable at that point, because:

> If you make changes to your docker-compose.yml configuration these
> changes are not reflected after running `docker compose restart` command.

Also make sure to do hard refresh on the website you are looking at the results using <kbd>CTRL+R</kbd> (in most browsers).

Comment: `environment:` can either be a list of strings `- VAR=value` or a mapping `VAR: value`, but you can't have both the `-` leading list indicator and also the `:` map syntax.

Comment: The syntax you show here is invalid: the `environment` section can be *either* a YAML list **or** a dictionary. What you have is a list of dictionaries and would fail with `services.<whatever>.environment contains {"MY_VAR": "foo"}, which is an invalid type, it should be a string`. See [the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#environment) tor  details.

Comment: Oh I confused it myself, thanks for letting me know, I removed the wrong part.

Comment: I mentioned in my question that I had already tried the -d flag, but that didn't help. I removed the duplicate values and that also didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: @methodical the `-d` flag has nothing to do with the problem. Please give us more of your debug traces, not only the results you see. Logs, browser tools, headers, did the app fully reload?

Comment: Please tell me what you need in order to debug further. Not as to say that I've exhaustively provided that, just that outside of showing/describing what happened when echoing out the proper envvar, and showing that it doesn't exist when I log out in my browser, I'm unaware of what else to provide.

Comment: @methodical I think either the container is not restarting or you are observing outdated/cached or data from a different host than you are operating on. Can you show some startup logs and verify the network tab shows you an up to date version from the expected host?

Comment: The only output that I have on startup is from `bin/build`, which shows the expected building taking place. Any changes that I make in the files are reflected when I reload the page, as it should since I have it set up to watch the files. When inspecting the container in the docker application, it shows the updated variables, I've added the screenshot of this to my original post.